# Curl caching a downloaded image?

Tags: php, curl

I have a script that tails a log file for a song change event. When that happens a Tweet is auto generated and sent to Twitter. Problem is that, I recently updated my script so that it also includes the album art with the Tweet. I am downloading the image using curl, posting the media, then removing the file for the next Tweet. What is throwing me off is that when the image displayed in the Tweet is for the previous song playing and not the current one. I want to know if I download a file using curl, then use php unlink command, would that same image be downloaded again? Here is my code below.

```
// Analyze prepared tweet for issues with length
    $tweeted = ($front . $fixedArtistNow . $hyphen . " " . $fixedTitleNow .     $tag);
    if (strlen($tweeted) <= 140) {

        try {
          //  $path = ("/home/soundcheck/public_html/images/artwork.png");
          //  if(unlink($path));
            // Grab album art from the song that is currently playing
            $fresh = date("y-m-d-G-i-s");
            $ch = curl_init('http://soundcheck.xyz:8000/playingart? sid=1?'.$fresh);
            var_dump($ch);
            $fp = fopen('/home/soundcheck/public_html/images/artwork.png', 'wb');
            curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($fp, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            fclose($fp);

          //  copy("/home/soundcheck/public_html/images/artwork.png","/home/soundcheck/public_html/images/album.png");

            // $twitter->send($front . $fixedArtistNow . $hyphen . " " . $fixedTitleNow . $tag);
            $media1 = $twitter->upload('media/upload', ['media' => '/home/soundcheck/public_html/images/artwork.png']);
            // $media2 = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => '/path/to/file/kitten2.jpg']);
            $parameters = [
                'status' => $tweeted,
                'media_ids' => implode(',', [$media1->media_id_string]),
            ];
            $result = $twitter->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
        //    unlink("/home/soundcheck/public_html/images/artwork.png");
```

The url I am getting the image from never changes but the image does if that makes any difference. If anyone knows a better way to download the album art, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I want to download the album art from the URL, use it for my tweet, remove the file and then repeat the process for the next Tweet. I am running this script using the watch command

Comment: watch -n 1 php script.php

Comment: cURL doesn't do any caching so the problem lies elsewhere.